# Using json4s-native library in a Spark cluster

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, json4s

I am trying to process data in an AWS EMR Spark cluster. For that, I have a Scala application which reads in raw JSON data from S3, parses it to Map[String, Any] with Scala's native **scala.util.parsing.json.JSON** library and **parseFull** method.

Then I have a recursive function, which flattens the nested JSON (So that Map[String, Any] would not contain any Maps inside it) and then I want to convert it back to JSON-formatted string to create a Spark DataFrame object.

For parsing a Map object to a JSON string, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27948884/1616049) solution by mohit.

Unfortunately, I had some problems with the org.json4s.native library in my IntelliJ and it said that it cannot resolve this dependency. (In hindsight, I now know it was a problem of not refreshing the project after updating .sbt file with the correct dependency. Now in IntelliJ the json4s.native library and its functions work.)

So at first, I used org.json4s.jackson.Json instead. But then the

```
Json(DefaultFormats).write(m)
```

line resulted in a string where integer numbers were converted to doubles and this was not correct.

So then I got my IntelliJ working with the json4s.native library and the result converted numbers correctly.

Now, however, I am having problems using this library in the Spark cluster. If I build the .jar locally, upload the file to S3, copy it to the EMR cluster and then run it with spark-submit, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json4s/native/Json$
```

And when I just try to import this library from the spark-shell, then I just get the response that this depencendy could not be resolved.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35464362) suggestion by Eli Leszczynski by trying to manually place the json4s-native jar file to the cluster, but his suggested **/home/hadoop/lib** does not work as /home/hadoop is a basically empty folder when I log in to hadoop@blabla.compute.amazonaws.com.

I found that my libraries may be found at **/usr/lib** or **/usr/lib/hadoop/lib** folders, but I copied the jar file there and still my own script failed.

So, how can I use **org.json4s.native** library in my Amazon EMR Spark cluster?

(Spark version 1.6 and I am using Scala version 2.10.5 for it to be compatible with the Spark version)

Answer (score 0):

If you have json4s in you sbt or pom.xl file, make sure the version is compatible with spark json for example for spark 3.3.x this version works:
"org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.6.6",